# android studio - "permission denied : connect"

Tags: android, android-studio, permission-denied

I have recently installed the android studio bundle from [this website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).

I installed this, pressed new project from the quick start menu, and followed through with the series of customisations.

After finishing the last page of the form and pressing "finish" , the following error message was displayed:

New Project Wizard

Permission denied: connect

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

At end of log:

```
INFO - .project.GradleProjectImporter - Permission denied: connect

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is there a log file in `<user>/.AndroidStudioPreview/system/log`?

Comment: It was a firewall issue. Removing built-in Norton Internet Sec. worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just **allow** `android studio` in your `firewall`, if you are using

1. **Tinyfirewall** - Click the autolearn so it will allow android studio in your firewall
2. If you are **not using any other firewall application** then you can turn off your `firewall`, but be aware that it will make your **`security low`**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in trying to connect with SDK Manager in order to download packages.
Same reply "Permission denied: connect".

I solved it (on Windows 7) by removing the read-only attribute that was set on the whole C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android directory.

Give it a try and let me know if it works! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I tried making everything readable but it didn't work. Finally I tried opening had the project I just created under `C:\Users\<me>\AndroidStudioProjects`. A message box came up asking if I wanted to open the firewall to Android Studio. I answered yes.  Now I can get into the project. I still go through the same issue with new projects.